# __call__ when calling a method inside the class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to understand the meaning of `__call__` (python3) . Wrote this to differentiate each method `__init__` , `__call__`, and test method.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class thara(object):

   def __init__(self):
        print("init called")

   def __call__(self):
       print("call called")

   def test(self):
       print("test called")

x=thara()  ### constructor calling here
x()   ## __call__  calling here
x.test() ## test method calling here
```

my question is when i initiate the `x.test()`, why it is not calling `__call__` ? what I'm thinking is, if i initiate the x.test() will initiate the instance `x()`, and it should call the   `__call__` method automatically.But according to my output `__call__` will call only when initiate `x()`.

can someone please explain.

Comment: Where did it say that `x.test()` will call `__call__`?  https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__

Comment: The behavior you observe makes perfect sense.  Please explain in more detail why it surprises you.  Or if you take that as an answer: This is just the way it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__

__call__ is called when instance is called like a function. And this is what you do with `x()`. `x.test()` is calling method of instance, not instance itself.